Render viewport image different from final render image
New to Blender. But I plan on making a scientific journal cover. I tried to create a test image following videos of YouTube but I keep getting a final rendered image that is very different from the active viewport image.
Also, the rendered image is missing a part on the bottom left corner and I do not know why.
Please could anyone suggest tips on correcting this?

The Outliner is mostly obscured by your render window, but I see a couple of objects in your scene that are hidden in viewport, but not in render (the eye icon is closed but the camera is not crossed out). I am guessing that one of these is the bedpost looking thing in the bottom right of the render, and the other is a light source or a large gray thing that is reflecting in the mirror background. Unhide these objects and see if the viewport and render now match. If they do, hide them in viewport AND render (by clicking the camera icon or just deleting both objects), and try rendering again.

I deleted the objects and it worked!
